# Google Apps Script How to align in a grid

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

How to align a button in the center of a cell within a grid?

```
  var buttonGrid = app.createGrid(3,2).setId('buttonGrid');
  buttonGrid.setStyleAttribute(row, column, attribute, value);
  buttonGrid.setWidget(0,0,multiButton);
  buttonGrid.setWidget(1,0,submitB);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
  var buttonGrid = app.createGrid(3,2).setId('buttonGrid');
  buttonGrid.setStyleAttribute("text-align", "center");
  buttonGrid.setWidget(0,0,multiButton);
  buttonGrid.setWidget(1,0,submitB);﻿
```

Answer (score -1):

If you only want to center the Button which is in a column or in a row, you have to use these properties of the object:

For Row:

```
grid.setRowStyleAttribute(row,"text-align", "center")
```

For Column:

```
grid.setColumnStyleAttribute(column,"text-align", "center")
```

Comment: Dentro de las políticas no especifica que se deba escribir en Ingles.